# Experimental feature asks me to provide feedback to someone who no longer works for SE

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-tools, wording, revision-redaction

♦ moderators have the ability to redact posts, e.g. to hide email addresses that were published by accident. There is an experimental feature to automatically apply redactions to subsequent revisions, which seems to work nicely, except that it wants me to mention that to [a person who no longer worked for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) at the time of this bug report (he's almost [back again](https://twitter.com/balpha/status/1523641670486704137), welcome!)

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if his former mailbox is filled with bug reports about this feature ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The text in question has been removed (as has the text declaring the feature to be experimental - I think that it has been around long enough to earn defacto *no-longer-an-experiment* status).

> Experimental?
> Contact balpha if broken?
> No longer the case

---

> balpha coming back?
> that is so awesome, we’re stoked!
> still, don’t contact him

Comment: I haven't verified it but it will probably take a while before I have to make a redaction, so I'll take your word for it :)

Comment: @Glorfindel the build went out on 18 Oct 21 15:18 UTC. Though I also haven't verified on prod (honestly, I never even saw this page before you pointed it out).

Comment: Well, with balpha back, I think a new haiku might be in order :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek done!